# Why Snapshots of the model, master, and tempdb databases are prohibited

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have been researching on snapshots and found at many places including [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#LimitsOnSourceDb)

> Snapshots of the model, master, and tempdb databases are prohibited.

My question is why?

**Edit**:

Actually because at one of our client's server I saw backup statements with Snapshot every hour for each DB at server, I am just wondering if this is useful and what will be the purpose of this

Backup statement

```
BACKUP DATABASE [master] TO VIRTUAL_DEVICE='{886}4' WITH SNAPSHOT,BUFFERCOUNT=1,BLOCKSIZE=1024,COPY_ONLY

BACKUP DATABASE [msdb] TO VIRTUAL_DEVICE='{886}4' WITH SNAPSHOT,BUFFERCOUNT=1,BLOCKSIZE=1024,COPY_ONLY
```

Answer (score -2):

taking snapshot on hourly manner is very useful for active databases and based on RTO (Recovery Time Objective) and RPO (Recovery Point Objective) which is less than 1 hour.

Model, master, and tempdb is passive default MSSQL databases.These database doesn't required to snapshot hourly as there wont be much changes occur every hour.One time daily backup is sufficient enough to rescue the database in the event of disaster.

Moreover, snapshopt will use up spaces and available resource (RAM and CPU).